# Image not uploaded to media folder in Django

Tags: python, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

Not able to upload image in Django Model.

I have installed Pillow , added MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT to my settings, added
`static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)` to my urls.py .

forms.py:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm) :
    class Meta :
        model = Post
        fields = ['name', 'image', 'description', 'age', 'cost', 'address', 'seller', 'phone', ]
```

post_edit.html:

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h2>New post</h2>
    <form method="POST" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

models.py:

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', null=True, blank=True)
```

urls.py:

```
path('edit/', views.post_edit, name='post_edit'),
```

views.py:

```
@login_required
def post_edit(request, pk) :
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST" :
        form = PostForm(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES, instance=post)
        if form.is_valid() :
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.save()
            return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
    else :
        form = PostForm(instance=post)
    return render(request, 'blog/post_edit.html', {'form' : form})
```

If I add an image to a new object , the image is not uploaded to `media/images/` .
With my modest level of understanding ,I'm not able to find the mistake . Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` form attribute to your template:

```
<form method="POST" class="post-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
```

From the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/file-uploads/#basic-file-uploads):

> Note that request.FILES will only contain data if the request method
>   was POST and the  that posted the request has the attribute
>   enctype="multipart/form-data"